# Create user with the replication access only

Tags: mysql, replication

Is it possible to have a user in mysql who can only have an access to the replication?

What I need is to monitor the replication to show if the replication is up and running or not. But, I want that the mysql user has only access to the replication infos, not everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-slave-status.html

You have to grant one of two permissions - SUPER or REPLICATION_CLIENT.
REPLICATION_CLIENT would be your minimum, so probably what you're after?